# How to cite an online brochure

Tags: bibtex, citing, online

I want to cite an online brochure, but there is no author name, it is a brochure of a company. How can I cite [this](http://www.telespazio.it/docs/brodoc/GCC_eng.pdf) in BibTeX?

Comment: Are you using `natbib`? Which bibliographical style do you use?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina yes, natbib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possibility; I used "Telespazio" in the author field, and `2010` for the year (see little text to the right, on the last page in the brochure):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{bbb.bib}
@misc{GCC,
year= "2010",
title = "{G}alileo {C}ontrol {C}entre",
url = "http://www.telespazio.it/docs/brodoc/GCC_eng.pdf",
howpublished = "Brochure",
author ="Telespazio"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\cite{GCC}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bbb}
\end{document}
```

[image]