# using @misc to cite a text but get odd output

Tags: citing, latex-misc, author

I am struggling with the bibtex for a long time, could you help me?

I want to cite a text from on a website without author. Therefore, I am using @misc in bibtex to cite it. The code is as follows:

```
@misc{sensitivity_and_specificity,
    key={sensitivity-specificity},
    Publisher={Emory University Medical School Evidence Based Medicine Course},
    title = {Sensitivity and Specificity},
    url = {http://www.med.emory.edu/EMAC/curriculum/diagnosis/sensand.htm},
    urldate = {2017-08-30}
}
```

But I only get the output which is not what I want to have[image]

As shown in the figure above, the colon ( : )  in front is not wanted, and in the end, the wort "Zugriffsdatum" is expected to be changed in English. I have serched online for long and find the code should be correct. I think the problem may be caused by the template which I am using right now. But I have totally no idea how to change it. Could you help me. Thank you in advance.

Best regards
YQ

Comment: And, what kind of template you use?

Comment: I wouldn't use the `@article` type for something that isn't an article.  I'd probably use `@misc`, or `@online` in biblatex

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni near enough, I reckon

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni I wouldn't say it is a duplicate of this question, since the issue is rather output-related. This question has certainly been answered to earlier anyway.

Comment: I think this link may help https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113810/how-to-cite-an-online-brochure

Comment: I don think it's a duplicate. As explained, I'm already using the command @misc but get a weird output probably because of the template. The template is provided by my university, I don"t know how to change. Really need you help.

Comment: @superweizen Can you please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) which includes the bib style you are using?